# Combine different kind of data in dygraphs?

Tags: dygraphs

I wan't to combine theoretical and experimental data in dygraphs. The theoretical data is for example a function, and has a lot of points to draw a smooth line, e.g.:

```
[1,x1], [2, x2], [3,x3] ...
```

for every second. Now I would like to add experimental data, which has only some points and not necessarily at the same time, for example:

```
[0.87, exp1][2.45, exp2] ...
```

How do I combine these two different kinds of data in one graph? I guess I could just add to my experimental data as much `NaN` points so that they both have the equal size at least. A lot of overhead for a simple task, but ok. If there wouldn't be the next problem:

Like in the example, I can not know beforehand if my measurement times exist already in my theoretical data, e.g. I could have the point `[3, x1]` as a function and measured [3.00001, exp1]. So I probably have to add also another `NaN` point at the exact time to my theoretical data. And maybe an exception if by any chance the time might be already there.

You can see where this is going... not a really beautiful way and a lot of overhead for such a - I suppose - simple and often used task.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add `NaN`s. dygraphs expects your data to be a tabular array, not independent series. See the [independent series example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/independent-series.html) for more details on how to work around this.

Comment: Thank you - too bad. ;) I wonder if this might be enough for a feature request? Because, not only it requires quite an amount of overhead in programming (getting all data sources the same size/style), but also decreases the web performance by a huge amount, since way more data has to be send. An example: I'm updating around 10k points multiple times a second. Adding some measurement points wouldn't be much more, but if every measurement has to be the same size as the original data, it suddenly increases the send data by a huge amount without a real need.

Comment: Sure, one could try to work around this as well, but then again: Being able to use independent series on one plot would solve a lot of overhead and problems.